# discord.py Use select menus inside slash_commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I have this code

```py
class DroppDownMenu(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Choose one option", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=[
       discord.SelectOption(label="CPU", description="The CPUs scores list"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="GPU", description="The GPUs scores list"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="RAM", description="The RAMs scores list"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="All", description="All scores lists")
    ])
    async def callback(self, select, interaction : discord.Interaction):
        if select.values[0] == "CPU":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919636461654046/CPU-Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_3.jpg")
        if select.values[0] == "GPU":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919674134904982/GPU_Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_5.jpg")
        if select.values[0] == "RAM":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919651070423100/RAM_scores_Super_Dark_Mode_4.jpg")
        if select.values[0] == "All":
            await interaction.response.send_message("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919636461654046/CPU-Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_3.jpg")        
            await interaction.followup.send("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919674134904982/GPU_Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_5.jpg")
            await interaction.followup.send("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919651070423100/RAM_scores_Super_Dark_Mode_4.jpg")

@commands.slash_command(name="scores_pcc1", description="Shows charts with benchmark of CPUs, GPUs or RAM")
    async def pcc1_scores_slash(self, ctx, part : Option(DroppDownMenu)):
        
        #await self.scores_buttons(ctx)
        pass
```

So basically I want to create a select menu inside of a slash command like this
[(Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tmUf.png)

But how to this
At the moment I only get errors

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two concepts here. There is the select *component* (`discord.ui.select`), this is typically sent after an interaction is invoked. What you are actually looking for is the `choices` parameter of the slash command `Option` (I'd love to link to the docs here, but they are quite empty at the moment).

---

Essentially, what you'll want to do is discard the entire `DroppDownMenu` class and move the logic from that callback to `pcc1_scores_slash`. You would generate the choices by changing the definition of `part` to something like `part : Option(str, 'StackOverflow provides great parameter descriptions', choices=['CPU', 'GPU', 'RAM', 'All'])` and then use the if-chain on the `part` variable in the slash command body something like this:

```py
@commands.slash_command(name='scores_pcc1', description='Shows charts with benchmark of CPUs, GPUs or RAM')
async def pcc1_scores_slash(self, ctx, part: Option(str, 'StackOverflow provides great parameter descriptions', choices=['CPU', 'GPU', 'RAM', 'All'])):
    if part in ('CPU', 'All'):
        await ctx.respond("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919636461654046/CPU-Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_3.jpg")
    if part in ('GPU', 'All'):
await ctx.respond("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919674134904982/GPU_Scores_Super_Dark_Mode_5.jpg")
    if part in ('RAM', 'All'):
await ctx.respond("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/838857610358292532/931919651070423100/RAM_scores_Super_Dark_Mode_4.jpg")
```